# Why can't I remove duplicates from a string in my text file?

Tags: ruby, duplicates, uniq

I'm trying to remove duplicate numbers from each line in a text file. For some reason, it won't remove the duplicate number 4. If I append an additional number after the 4, it works fine and the duplicate 4's are removed.

```
def remove_dup(str)
  str.split(",").uniq.join(",")
end

File.open('pad.txt','r').each do |line|
  puts remove_dup(line)
end
```

My input 'pad.txt' file:

```
1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4
2,3,4,5,5
```

My output:

```
1,2,3,4,4
2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps since you are getting the string from a text file, there is a `\n` at the end of the string. Hence, the last `4` is actually `4\n`.

Try this to see if it works:

```
def remove_dup(str)
    str.chomp.split(",").uniq.join(",")
end
```

The [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) method will remove the carriage return characters from the end of the string.